# Trying to power a 100-watt Cree Xpe array as efficiently as possible with dimming

Tags: power-supply, led, power, driver

I've recently purchased a 100-watt Cree 30-module XPE multichip

http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-100W-Red-Blue-Dual-Colors-Cree-XPE-LED-for-100-Watt-Grow-Light-Bulb-Lamp-DIY-/231312859741?ssPageName=ADME:X:RTQ:US:1123

How do I go about efficiently powering this chip?  Having next to no electrical experience, I am overwhelmed by the different types of drivers on the market.  I'd also like to make it dimmable if possible.

Comment: Please post a link to the datasheet instead of a link to the eBay auction.  eBay auction will expire in a matter of few months, link will go dead, question will lose context.

Comment: And it's 30 LEDs, not 20.

Comment: Thanks Nick... here's the datasheet http://www.cree.com/~/media/Files/Cree/LED%20Components%20and%20Modules/XLamp/Data%20and%20Binning/XLampXPE.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is not a place to look for specific LED driver models. That said, in general terms:

1) Do not buy anything else from that buyer. Anybody who advertises a 22 volt, 3 amp LED as 100 watts is untrustworthy (as in, liar). For instance, they claim that your module is compatible with their 100 watt driver. Nope, so sorry. Minimum voltage for their drivers is 30 volts, much higher than your module accepts.

2) I've tried to do the math using the published data sheet (pdf from http://www.cree.com/LED-Components-and-Modules/Products/XLamp/Discrete-Directional/XLamp-XPE) and I cannot see for the life of me how they get their numbers. 6 blue LEDs will, in fact, drop a nominal 21 volts at 1 amp. The reds, however, just don't work out.

So, since I'm not sure how the individual LEDs are hooked up, I'd have to recommend using a dimmable 50 watt LED driver. Any more and I'd look for damage somewhere.

Also, I'm not sure if you're aware of it, but your module MUST be mounted on a fairly thick metal plate, preferably aluminum, if you want anywhere near maximum power. If you don't do this, you will overheat the LEDs.

Comment: WhatRoughBeast, thank you so much!  I'm a computer guy and have plenty of strong fans and heatsinks, so I'm not worried by heat issues at the moment

Comment: WhatRoughBeast, thank you so much!  I'm a computer guy and have plenty of strong fans and heatsinks, so I'm not worried by heat issues at the moment.  I just can't figure out the math either, but I'm no electrician.  I asked the seller to recommend a driver and he recommended http://www.ebay.com/itm/60W-60-Watt-High-Power-LED-Driver-Waterproof-Power-Supply-Output-DC-20V-36V-2A-/231283416607?ssPageName=STRK:MESE:IT.  I won't be buying anything more from him for sure.  Would you be willing to recommend a dimmable LED Driver for me?  I suppose this would be the easiest route.  Thanks again Beast!

Comment: I got into building these as the grow lights I was buying were listed at 58 and 28 watts respectively... upon a large purchase of these I found out they were consuming 18 and 9 watts respectively...there was no way they could be giving off the lumens they claimed.

Comment: I got into building these as the grow lights I was buying were listed at 58 and 28 watts respectively... upon a large purchase of these I found out they were consuming 18 and 9 watts respectively...there was no way they could be giving off the lumens they claimed.  I had another similar experience with downlights I purchased.  I'm now inclined to buy the modules from a Cree reseller and put them together.  I just need to educate myself more on how to determine the power requirements of the modules.